# Use case for more than one init block in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I notice that classes in Kotlin can have more than one init block. If so, they are executed in sequence.

What is a good use case for having more than one?

Comment: yes they are executed in order of declaration. if you are inititialising collections and it takes a fair bit of code, you could have one to init each collection separately

Comment: Could you elaborate more in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: imo there is no good use case for multiple init blocks. Sure, it's _possible_, but you're better off not doing it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the following snippet.

```
class Foo() {
  val x = Bar.getValue()

  init {
    // check the validity of x and abort if invalid
  }

  val y = Cow.getValue(x)  // requires x to be valid

  init {
    // continue with initialization
  } 
}
```

Since primary constructor cannot have any code, the above situation would not be possible  without multiple init blocks.  In other words, the ability to have multiple init blocks helps tackle dependencies involving properties during initialization; more so, when properties are read-only.

**Update on 10/16/2021**: We can achieve the same behavior by moving the assignment of read-only (RO) properties into a single `init` block.  However, by doing so, we will separate the declaration of a RO property and its initialization.  In comparison, multiple `init` blocks help keep the declaration and initialization of RO properties together while allowing any dependent computation to follow the property initialization.  Consequently, the code is a bit cleaner, easy to read/understand, and modular (as described by @mightyWOZ's reply).

Comment: But this we can do in a single init block also then why multiple init block is required.

Comment: Umesh, I have added an update to answer your question.  Hope this helps,

Answer (score 6):

One use case would be to `modularize` `class` `initialization`.

If a class have multiple dependencies and ***initialization of each dependency is non-trivial, then it makes sense to have an individual `init` block for each dependency initialization, so that your code remains manageable.*** you can have a single init block but the code would be hard to follow and manage.

I think [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) applies here.

For example, let's say we have a class which have multiple dependencies, if you use multiple init blocks, your code would be

```
// Initialization code for dependency 1
init{
 // complex calculations for dependency 1 initialization
 }

// Initialization code for dependency 2
init{ 
   // complex calculations for dependency 2 initialization
 }

// Initialization code for dependency n
init{
// complex calculations for nth dependency initialization 
}
```

Here your initialization looks clear, and you can see which init block does what.

If however, you use a single init block, your code would be

```
// Initialization code for all dependencies
init{
   // complex calculations for 1st dependency initialization 
   // complex calculations for 2nd dependency initialization 
   // complex calculations for nth dependency initialization 
}
```